# Add attribute to filter AND condition magento

Tags: magento

I m trying to filter out the collection by name which can start from a,b,c and d alphabets.

I have tried following codes

> 1) addFieldToFilter( 'm_name',array('like' => 'a%'), 'm_name',array('like' => 'b%'), 'm_name',array('like' => 'c%') )
>
> 2) addFieldToFilter(array( array('m_name','like' => 'a%'), array('m_name','like' => 'b%'), array('m_name','like' => 'c%'), ))

But both of these are displaying the collection of names starting with alphabet 'a' only.(not b,c,and d). Please help me for getting the right collection.

I have also tried this code
$collection = Mage::getModel('manufacturers/manufacturers')->getCollection()
                                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId())
                                ->addFieldToFilter('m_name',array(array('like'=>'a'.'%')) , array('like'=>'b'.'%'),array('like'=>'c'.'%'))
  ->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();

But still it is displaying collection of names starting with alphabet 'a' only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not searching for `AND`, but for `OR`.

If you `AND` a `LIKE a%` and a `LIKE b%` you'll always get an empty result. That's because the same attribute value can only start with `a OR b`, but never with `a AND b`.

To define an `OR` filter for a specific attribute you can use a single `addFieldToFilter()` call and pass an array of arrays to it:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        'm_name',
        array(
            array(
                'like' => 'a%'
            ),
            array(
                'like' => 'b%'
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc')
          ->addFieldToFilter('name',array(array('like'=>'a%'), array('like'=>'b%'), array('like'=>'c%'), array('like'=>'d%')))
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) {
      echo $product->getName() . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: An error is occuring whenever i add (addAttributeToSort or addAttributeToSelect).....Error says::Call to undefined method myPackageName_myModuleName_Model_Mysql4_myFolderName_Collection::addAttributeToSort()

Comment: replace this code only in your above collection ->addFieldToFilter('m_name',array(array('like'=>'a%'), array('like'=>'b%'), array('like'=>'c%'), array('like'=>'d%')))

Comment: ok Thanku error is solved.I have not put down the closing bracket correctly.my code was like this:->addFieldToFilter('m_name',array(array('like'=>'a%')) , array('like'=>'b%'), array('like'=>'c%'))

Comment: Now I m trying to filter out the collection by name which can start from range m to p alphabets.$mtopname = $collection->addFieldToFilter('m_name',array(array('like'=>'m%'), array('like'=>'n%'), array('like'=>'o%'), array('like'=>'p%')))
                        ->load();But i am always getting the result of first collection that is a to d collection.

Comment: ok solved by using this function echo $mtopname->getSelect() . It will give magento collection in sql query form and then we can analyse the result.